# How can that view be achieved? Collage / Magazine Products

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how that kind of view is called and how you can achieve it with HTML/CSS: http://www.amazine.com/

To me, it looks like it's like a mashup or magazine for products and looks pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to make such a layout, you can try something like this :

```css
.container{
  position : relative;
  border: blue solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  }

.container h2{
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  top: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 50;
  }

.container .second{
   position: absolute; 
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 170px;
}

.container .third{
   position: absolute; 
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h2>Some text</h2>
  <img class="first" src="http://lorempixel.com/180/290/"/>
  <img class="second" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/200/"/>
  <img class="third" src="http://lorempixel.com/110/170/"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <img class="first" src="http://lorempixel.com/190/280/"/>
  <img class="second" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/220/"/>
  <img class="third" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/160/"/>
</div>
```